# .Net Location Service : Use only GPS data

Tags: .net, gps, geolocation, location

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207054(v=vs.105).aspx)

> The Microsoft Location Service allows you to create location-aware applications for Windows Phone. The service obtains location data from multiple sources such as GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular. It can use one or more of these sources to deduce the location of the Windows Phone, balancing performance with power utilization depending on an application’s needs. The location is exposed to applications through an event-driven managed code interface.

Can I manage to use only GPS to receive location?